# Where to get libcurl for Windows with --compressed option enabled?

Tags: windows, command-line, firefox, curl, tls

So, I'm copying some curl commands from developer tools on Firefox and they often include the flag --compressed and even if removing it often makes command execute succesfully, my aim is to be able to run commands with this flag.

At the moment this is what I'm getting when using that flag:

```
curl: option --compressed: the installed libcurl version doesn't support this
```

Is there any version compiled for Windows that support this tag? I tried multiple of the versions available but with no luck.

Comment: Try the cywin version of curl. The --compressed option appears to be enabled.

Comment: Thank you but even if I just tried I'm still getting the "curl: option --compressed: the installed libcurl version doesn't support this" error.

Comment: `curl --compressed "http://www.google.com"` in a cygwin `bash` shell works for me ...

Comment: I checked again and using curl package doesn't have "--compressed option" but the package mingw...curl has it included. It's not a perfect solution because I planed to use it running Powershell scripts but it could work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here: https://curl.se/download.html#Win64

`--compressed` is supported